# Binary Search Same items & Store and Display them

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

This is my main search algorithm for multiple items using binary and separate function. I need someone to refactor my approach.

```
private int Multisearch(TYPE key){

        int ind = binarySearchComparator(key);


     // If element is not present 
        if (ind == -1) 
            return -1; 

        // Count elements on left side. 
        int count = 1; 
        int left = ind - 1; 
        int i = 1;
        while (left >= 0 && (comparator.compare(list[left], key)) == 0) 
        { 
            lol[i] = list[left];      // store left found elements in array here  
            i++;
            count++; 
            left--; 

        } 

        // Count elements  
        // on right side. 
        int right = ind + 1; 

        try{


        while (right < list.length && (comparator.compare(list[right], key)) == 0) 
        { 
            lol[i] = list[right];      // store right found elements in array here  
            i++;
            count++; 
            right++; 



        } 

        }catch(Exception e){

        }


        return count; 
    }



private int binarySearchComparator(TYPE key) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = count - 1;

        while (low <= high) {

            int mid = (low + high) / 2 ;
            TYPE midVal = list[mid];
            int cmp = comparator.compare(midVal, key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                return mid; // key found
        }

        return -1;  // key not found.
    }
```

**Above code is my approach and my backup. I want you guys to use a binary search to look for multiple items and store them somewhere for it to display to the user as the user is filtering items by gender and the binarysearch function will search items that is " Male " and display them all for the user.**

I need it to search multiple items and display/store them somewhere else to display it to the user.

This is like a filtering function by the way if any kind soul is able to help me out. I will greatly appreciate it!

**Well if you can actually count the occurrence of same item/object as well as store them to display later. I will even greatly appreciate that approach! Please show me how! Thanks!**

**Sorted List Interface**

```
public interface SortedListInterface <TYPE extends Comparable<TYPE>> {


    public boolean add(TYPE element);


    public TYPE get(int index);


    public int search(TYPE element);


    public TYPE remove(int index);


    public void clear();




public int getLength();


public boolean isEmpty();


public boolean isFull();
```

}

**SearchComparator Class**

```
public class MobileSearch implements Comparator<Student>{


    private String type;

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }




    @Override
    public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {


        int result = 0;



        if(this.type.equals("mobile")){
            result = student1.getMobileNo().compareTo(student2.getMobileNo());
            System.out.print(result+"mobile");
        }

        else if(this.type.equals("name")){
            result = student1.getName().getFullName().compareTo(student2.getName().getFullName());
             System.out.println(result+"name");
        }

        else if(this.type.equals("group")){

                 result = student1.getGroup().compareTo(student2.getGroup());
                 System.out.print(result+"group");

             }



        return result;
    }

}
```

**SortedArrayList Implementation**

```
public class SortedArrayList<TYPE extends Comparable<TYPE>> implements SortedListInterface<TYPE>{

  //Data Types  

  private TYPE[] list;
  private int length;
  private static final int SIZE = 10;

  private Comparator<? super TYPE> comparator;
  private int count;


  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SortedArrayList(Comparator<? super TYPE> c) {
        comparator = c;
        list = (TYPE[]) new Comparable[SIZE]; // No way to verify that 'list' only contains instances of 'T'.

        /* NOTE: Following is not allowed.
        list = new T[SIZE]; // Cannot create a generic array of T
        */
    }




  // Constructors

  public SortedArrayList() {
    this(SIZE);
  }

  public SortedArrayList(int size) {
    length = 0;
    list = (TYPE[]) new Comparable[SIZE]; // an array of instances of a class implementing Comparable interface and able to use compareto method but its overidden instead
  }



  // Setter & Getters

  @Override
  public int getLength() {
    return length;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return length == 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isFull() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void clear() {
    length = 0;
  }


  // Array Expansion

  private boolean isArrayFull() {
    return length == list.length;
  }

  private void expandArray() {
    TYPE[] oldList = list;
    int oldSize = oldList.length;

    list = (TYPE[]) new Object[2 * oldSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++) // copy old array elements into new array elements
      list[i] = oldList[i];

  }




  // ADT METHODs


  // Add New Elements Function


  @Override
//    public boolean add(TYPE element) {
//        int i = 0;
//
//        while (i < length && element.compareTo(list[i]) > 0) // return 0 with equal , return more than 1 if element larger than list[i] , return -1 if less
//        {
//            i++;
//        }
//
//        makeRoom(i + 1);
//        list[i] = element;
//        length++;
//        return true;
//    }


  public boolean add(TYPE element) {

        boolean result = false;
        if (count == 0) {
            list[0] = element;
            count = 1;
            result = true;
        }
        else {
            if (!isFull()) {
                int i = 0;
                while (list[i] != null) {
                    if (element.compareTo(list[i]) < 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (list[i] != null) {
                    for (int j = count - 1; j >= i; j--) {
                        list[j + 1] = list[j];
                    }
                }
                list[i] = element;
                count++;
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


  private void makeRoom(int index) {  // accepts given index
    int newIndex = index - 1;
    int lastIndex = length - 1;

    for (int i = lastIndex; i >= newIndex; i--) 
      list[i + 1] = list[i];

  }



  //Remove Elements Function

  @Override
  public TYPE remove(int index) {  // accepts given index

    TYPE result = null;

    if ( index >= 1 && index <= length ) {

      result = list[index - 1];

      if (index < length) 
        removeGap(index);

      length--;
    }

    return result;
  }

  private void removeGap(int index) { // accepts given index and remove the gap where the element its removed

    int removedIndex = index - 1;
    int lastIndex = length - 1;

    for (int i = removedIndex; i < lastIndex; i++) 
      list[i] = list[i + 1]; // shifts elements back to remove the gap

  }


  // Get Element

  @Override
  public TYPE get(int index) { // accepts given index and return the object

    TYPE object = null;

    if ( index >= 1 && index <= length) 
      object = list[index - 1];

    return object;

  }


  // Search Algorithms

  @Override
// public boolean search(TYPE element) {
//    boolean found = false;
//    
//    int lo = 0;
//    int hi = count - 1;
//    
//    while (lo <= hi) {
//        int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
//        if (list[mid].compareTo(element) < 0) {
//            lo = mid + 1;
//        }
//        else if (list[mid].compareTo(element) > 0) {
//            hi = mid - 1;
//        }
//        else if (list[mid].compareTo(element) == 0) {
//            found = true;
//            break;
//        }
//          return found
//    }

  public int search(TYPE element) {

            return exponentialSearch(element);

    }



  private boolean binarySearchComparable(TYPE element) {
        boolean found = false;
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = count - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
            if (list[mid].compareTo(element) < 0) {
                lo = mid + 1;
            }
            else if (list[mid].compareTo(element) > 0) {
                hi = mid - 1;
            }
            else if (list[mid].compareTo(element) == 0) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Single");
        return found;
    }


    private int exponentialSearch(TYPE key){

        int ind = binarySearchComparator(key);


     // If element is not present 
        if (ind == -1) 
            return -1; 

        // Count elements on left side. 
        int count = 1; 
        int left = ind - 1; 
        int i = 1;
        while (left >= 0 && (comparator.compare(list[left], key)) == 0) 
        { 
//            lol[i] = list[left];
            System.out.println(left+"lefttest");
            i++;
            count++; 
            left--; 

        } 

        // Count elements  
        // on right side. 
        int right = ind + 1; 

        try{


        while (right < list.length && (comparator.compare(list[right], key)) == 0) 
        { 
            System.out.println(right+"righttest");
//            lol[i] = arr[right];
            i++;
            count++; 
            right++; 



        } 

        }catch(Exception e){

        }


        return count; 
    }

    private int binarySearchComparator(TYPE key) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = count - 1;

        while (low <= high) {

            int mid = (low + high) / 2 ;
            TYPE midVal = list[mid];
            int cmp = comparator.compare(midVal, key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                return mid; // key found
        }

        return -1;  // key not found.
    }













  //To String Method

  @Override
  public String toString() {

    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
      result += list[i] + "\n";

    return result;

  }



}
```

**Name Class**

```
public class Name {

    // Data Types

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;


    // Constructors

    public Name() {
    }

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // setter

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // getter

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getFullName(){
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name{" + "firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + '}';
    }







}
```

**Student Class**

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{


   // Data Types 

   private String studID; 
   private Name name;
   private String gender;
   private String icNo;
   private String mobileNo;
   private Course course;
   private String group;
   private String dOB;


   // Constructors

   public Student() {
   }


    public Student(String studID, Name name, String gender, String icNo, String mobileNo, Course course, String group, String dOB) {
        this.studID = studID;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.icNo = icNo;
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
        this.course = course;
        this.group = group;
        this.dOB = dOB;
    }



   public Student(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


   // setter


    public void setStudID(String studID) {
        this.studID = studID;
    }

   public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void setIcNo(String icNo) {
        this.icNo = icNo;
    }

    public void setMobileNo(String mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public void setdOB(String dOB) {
        this.dOB = dOB;
    }


    // getter

    public String getStudID() {
        return studID;
    }

    public Name getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public String getIcNo() {
        return icNo;
    }

    public String getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public String getdOB() {
        return dOB;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + "name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + ", icNo=" + icNo + ", mobileNo=" + mobileNo + ", course=" + course + ", group=" + group + ", dOB=" + dOB + '}';
    }


   @Override
   public int compareTo(Student object) { // Sort according to name if name same then sort according to gender and so on.

    int c = this.name.getFullName().compareTo(object.getName().getFullName());

    if(c == 0)
        c = this.gender.compareTo(object.getGender()); 

    if(c == 0)
        c = this.icNo.compareTo(object.getIcNo());  

    if(c == 0)
        c = this.mobileNo.compareTo(object.getMobileNo());

    if(c == 0)
        c = this.group.compareTo(object.getGroup());

    if(c == 0)
        c = this.dOB.compareTo(object.getdOB());

    return c;

  }

   public static Student[] sort(Student[] object,String category){


       Student[] array;

       if(category.equals("ID")){
         for (int i=1; i < object.length; i++) {
           for(int j = 0 ; j < object.length - i ; j++)
               if( (object[j].getGender().compareTo(object[j+1].getGender())) > 0 ){
                    Student lol = object[j];
                    object[j] = object[j+1];
                    object[j+1] = lol;
              }
       }



   }
        array = object;
       return array;
  }


}
```

**Course Class**

```
public class Course {


    // Data Types

    private String courseCode;
    private String courseName;
    private double courseFee;


    // Constructors

    public Course() {
    }

    public Course(String courseCode, String courseName, double courseFee) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseFee = courseFee;
    }

    // setter

    public void setCourseCode(String courseCode) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseFee(double courseFee) {
        this.courseFee = courseFee;
    }


    // getter

    public String getCourseCode() {
        return courseCode;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public double getCourseFee() {
        return courseFee;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CourseCode = " + courseCode + "Course Name = " + courseName + "Course Fee = " + courseFee;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data are already sorted, you won't get faster than binary search **O(log n)**. If there are more than one match, find one match and than iterate forward (until no more matches found) and backward (until no more matches found) from it to get all matches.(or if you only need the index of first and last match, you can replace the iterating part by again binary search for the first / last matching one. That would reduce complexity to **O(n)** no matter how many matches there are)

This takes **O(log n) + O(#matches)**

If that is not fast enough for you, try profiling your implementation to find the bottleneck where further optimization attempts make most sense.

Comment: Are you sure my approach is actually O(log n)? I am actually doing what you are doing in my approach above.

I found the mid with binary search function and use another separate function to find the left elements from the mid and right elements from the mid for matches.

Imagine if I have huge data say 1000 data I would need to iterate through 1k of them left and right from the mid lol.

This is equivalent to O(N) ain't it?

Comment: Or perhaps O ( Log N^2 ) ?

Comment: You are saying my approach is O( log n ) + O ( N ) ?? What’s the final value then?

Comment: @Cash: if *N* is tin the order of *n* the algorithm becomes O(n) because the result contains O(n) elements. If *N* is below a constant, the algorithm is *O(log n)*.

Comment: @Cash: if you are not sure that your implementation has the expected complexity, you need to profile its performance for different n values.

Comment: Hmm I am actually here looking for binary implementation of searching multiple same items and displaying them instead of evaluating the time complexity.

Comment: I am assigned task to implement a efficient binary search not to derive the big O manually from the code. But you can let know the final time complexity based on what I stated that my algorithm searches the item in the middle with binary search and then search left with sequential search until no matches found and searches right with sequential search too until no matches is found so what is the time compelexity? O( Log N ) + O ( N )